# Java Swing GUI - Problem

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have created a GUI in Java using swings with the help of Netbeans IDE.

Now the problem is when I click on "Preview Design", the look and feel of the GUI is that of my O.S i.e Windows XP but when I click on "Run" button to run the application, then the look and feel of the GUI is metalic.

How can I set the tone of the GUI. (It would be more better if the answer is w.r.t Netbeans IDE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [UIManager](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) class.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Will change the Look & Feel to whatever the default on the system is.  You have to call it before you construct any UI objects, `void main(String[] args)` is a good place.

Answer (score 3):

In your main method, explicitly tell Swing which L&F to use, a la

```
// Metal! Woo!
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

or

```
// Fit in. Be boring.
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

etc.